# Access 2010 Update Query Error

Tags: ms-access-2010

i am trying to create an update query that accepts parameters for the values that need updating. My query:

```
PARAMETERS FirstName Text ( 255 ), LastName Text ( 255 ), AccessLevel Short;
UPDATE   
tblUser SET tblUser.FName = [FirstName],   
tblUser.LName = [LastName],   
tblUser.AccessLevelID = [AccessLevel]
WHERE (((tblUser.UserID)=[Forms]![frmEditUser]![subfrmUsers].[Form]![UserID]));
```

And my VBA code that runs when the edit button is pushed by the user:

```
If valid Then
    DoCmd.SetParameter "FirstName", Forms!frmEditUser!txtFName
    DoCmd.SetParameter "LastName", Forms!frmEditUser!txtLName
    DoCmd.SetParameter "AccessLevel", Forms!frmEditUser!cmbAccessLevel
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("qryEditUserRecord")
    MsgBox "Success: Record edits have been applied", _
        vbOKOnly, "Record Edits Success"
    Me.Refresh
End If
```

valid is just a boolean that is true when all controls have data. The error is:

```
The object does not contain the Automation object "Drew"
```

Where Drew is the current records FName value. This error occurs at the first SetParameter command and I am unaware of the problem or how to fix it. The query runs as expected if I prompt outside the VBA code, but that is what I need for this to work.

Comment: It all seems like a very long and complicated way to change the values in the subform to the values in the main form and I can't see why you would want to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a very unintuitive solution that I found here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZA/accessdev/thread/8538bd05-abc3-4cad-b284-bcbf7fa3dd69

When dealing with a string parameter the DoCmd.Parameter "para", """" & Me.txtName & """"

I have no idea why it needs the four double quotes and an & but it does.

Comment: Your query isn't surrounding the string paramenters (FName and LName) with quotes. That means you need to include the quotes in with the parameters. You're concatenating the quotes around your input string using the ampersands (VB/VBA operator). When you put double quotes within a string, you need to escape them with another double quote in VB/VBA. Hopefully, that makes some sense.